# Inline-block vs margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

Im trying to use `margin: auto;` at the same time as i'm using the `display: inline-block;` css. Before i'm putting in the `inline-block` code it worked fine and the `div` was centered using margin auto. But now its not working anymore.

I want the Divs logo and contact_info to be inline and the div `.inner` to be centered.

```
.inner {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.contact_info {
  float: right;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
    <div class="inner"> <!-- Top header -->
    <div class="logo">
    Logga här
    </div>

    <div class="contact_info">

        <h4> Vikbo Bil & Motor AB </h4>
        <p> Ekkällavägen 6 </p>
        <p> 610 24 Vikbolandet </p>
        <p> 0125 500 71 </p>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your html as well?

Comment: margin: auto with inline elements doesn't work because inline elements doesn't have width property. If the inner is wrapped by another div you can set text-align: center on that div and it will center the contents of .inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove inline-block from `.inner` class.

```
display: inline-block;
```

makes an element well..inline. meaning it only takes as much space as it's width, and allows other inline elements to take the remaining space in the page if they can fit in.

what you want, is to create the `.inner` div a block element, which, even though there might be extra space after the div has taken the space for it's own width, won't let any other element take up that space. meaning, it'll be the only element in that row.

so you can use `margin: auto` to make it center.

I see you've used `float` placement on logo and `contact_info` meaning they'll not be fitting in the `div.inner`. you should use `display: inline-block` on these divs, so they inline and inside the `div.inner`.

see if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnnndnzv/) satisfies all your needs?

Comment: Your answer makes the div centered, but its making the div that floats right to get outside the paddig-bottom

Comment: I know, i added the solution for it in the last paragraph.

Comment: @mackeemackee i added a fiddle in my answer. check if that's how you want your divisions to show.

Comment: I think i got it now... thx for the help! And again, sry for the bad information at first!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the inline-block property on your "inner" div :

```css
.inner {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 40px;
background: blue;
}

.logo {
float: left;
  background: red;
}

.contact_info {
float: right;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="contact_info">contact_info</div>
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It gets .inner centered. But .contact_info that has som <p> gets some of the <p> beneath the .inner and the padding-bottom not working

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or paste your html code? how's @TomRns or I or any one here supposed to know there's a <p> inside inner?

Comment: Sry, i have now added html

Comment: @mackeemackee I would add a fixed height on the blocks or would use flexboxes... But it's difficult to guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Atoom Im trying to not use a fixed height on the blocks, i can fix the problem using that but i think its more elegant if its done only using paddom top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can do problem solve using this code

```
.inner{
width:100%
margin:0 auto;
display: block;
height: 100px;
}

.logo{
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
}

.contact_info{
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
}
```